# Open one App in Android from a class of other Applications

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

I am building one Android Application, which needed to be opened ( running in the background), when any music player App is opened. Example - default player, any music player apps like soundcloud etc. I can open my App when a music player opens by capturing the sound but it also opens whenever a alert music there ( like Facebook or whatsapp or SMS alert). Please let me know if there is any solution to this. Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can detect when a media app is **OPENED**. However you CAN detect when a media app starts playing music, have a look here:

[Android: Detect another application has started playing audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576160/android-detect-another-application-has-started-playing-audio)

If you know what apps to listen for you can detect other apps starting:

[Android, Detect when other apps are launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched?rq=1)