# Getting Information from Music App

Tags: android

I'm building an app right now that needs to get the song name of the current song being played on an Android device as well as its current progress (i.e. 17 seconds in of a 2 minute 32 second song).

I was wondering if retrieving this information is possible and if it is, I would like some suggestions and pointers as to how to retrieve this data.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576160/android-detect-another-application-has-started-playing-audio). Might be what you're looking for.