# How to detect voice/video chat event from an other application

Tags: android

I'm building a music player and it should be paused when a voice/video chat is taking place. I know I could use an audio focus listener but is there any other way to achieve this?

I've googled a lot but still can't find anything related.

Is there any broadcast event like `VOICE/VIDEO_CHAT_START(END)` or `AUDIO_RECORD_START(END)`? Or something like `TelephonyManager` I could add a listener to?

This question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576160/android-detect-another-application-has-started-playing-audio). I want to detect events for audio recording instead of playing to be exactly.

Comment: Nope.. Audio Focus is better way to go with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Detect another application has started playing audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576160/android-detect-another-application-has-started-playing-audio)

Comment: It's different because I'm not detecting audio play events. It's audio recording instead.

Comment: did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610464/stopping-starting-music-on-incoming-calls

Comment: I'm using a PhoneStateListener already. But it works only for phone calls, not for voice chat.